# Using the ping command on my VirtualBox Debian System returns no route but I can still connect to websites

Tags: debian, virtualbox, ping, error-handling

For further clarification, I'm using a bridged adapter on VirtualBox and it's set to allow VMs (it is also using the correct adapter).

This is what the terminal responds with after running the command.

```
ping google.com

PING google.com(kul08s08-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4001:80d::200e)) 56 data bytes

From 2001:f40:901:fdf3:7e8b:caff:fe3e:ee18 (2001:f40:901:fdf3:7e8b:caff:fe3e:ee18) icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: No route

From 2001:f40:901:fdf3:7e8b:caff:fe3e:ee18 (2001:f40:901:fdf3:7e8b:caff:fe3e:ee18) icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: No route

From 2001:f40:901:fdf3:7e8b:caff:fe3e:ee18 (2001:f40:901:fdf3:7e8b:caff:fe3e:ee18) icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: No route

From 2001:f40:901:fdf3:7e8b:caff:fe3e:ee18 (2001:f40:901:fdf3:7e8b:caff:fe3e:ee18) icmp_seq=4 Destination unreachable: No route

From 2001:f40:901:fdf3:7e8b:caff:fe3e:ee18 (2001:f40:901:fdf3:7e8b:caff:fe3e:ee18) icmp_seq=5 Destination unreachable: No route

^C

--- google.com ping statistics ---

5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +5 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4067ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using IP6 addresses for the PING. Try using `ping -4 google.com` instead.